# Approximate F-test of the intercept with pbkrtest

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm currently trying out the `pbkrtest` package. The test of the fixed effect (`f1`, in the example below) doesn't pose any problem.

```
## Not run:
library(lme4)
library(pbkrtest)

# large model:
m1 <- lmer(x ~ f1 + (1|ID) + (0 + f1|ID), data)
```

When I want to obtain an approximate F-test based on the Kenward-Roger approach for `f1`, I specify this model:

```
# small model
m2 <- lmer(x ~ 1 + (1|ID) + (0 + f1|ID), data)
```

and then:

```
KRmodcomp(m1, m2)
```

However, what kind of model should I specify if I would like to get an approximate F-test of the intercept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To test a intercept less model (but including `f1`) you need to simply specify it (both ways are equivalent):

```
m3 <- lmer(x ~ 0 + f1 + (1|ID) + (0 + f1|ID), data)
```

or

```
m3 <- lmer(x ~ f1 + (1|ID) + (0 + f1|ID) - 1, data)
```

and then compare those:

```
KRmodcomp(m1, m3)
```

You can also get a test of all effects in (including the intercept) using function `mixed` in package [`afex`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/afex/index.html), which does exactly this.

---

Example taken from `?KRmodcomp`

```
require(pbkrtest)
fmLarge <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
## removing Days
fmSmall <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
KRmodcomp(fmLarge,fmSmall)

#removing intercept:
fmNoIntercept <- lmer(Reaction ~ 0 + Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
KRmodcomp(fmLarge,fmNoIntercept)
```

Comment: It makes perfect sense, however, when I'm comparing m1 and m2 `KRmodcomp` runs smoothly, whereas when I'm comparing m1 and m3 I get this error message: "Error in KRmodcomp.mer(m1, m3): Models have either equal fixed mean stucture or are not nested". Any idea?

Comment: @vikkor Hmm, sounds strange. If yours does not work you need to post the data. I added a **working** example.

Comment: Curiously, if I use the `mixed` function from `afex` (as you suggested) with method set to "KR" I do not get that error. And, I don't get the error if I use `PBmodcomp` instead of `KRmodcomp`. I'll have to dig into this to understand where the problem is. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Note that if `f1` is a factor, then removing the intercept makes no sense, and all you'll get is a different dummy coding. This could cause the models not nested error.